# Does adding source map support to a library will change the stack traces in projects it is added to?

Tags: node.js, typescript, source-maps

I'm developing a plugin for the headless CMS Strapi. I recently switched to typescript and I want to add source map support to my plugin.

But I'm unsure if the addition will affect the whole application where the plugin is installed.

I couldn't find any resources on the subject. Any idea?